# How to make it work? C# GridView Delete Line

Tags: c#, sql, database, gridview, datagridview

```
protected void gv_pedidos_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
{
    int idPedido = Convert.ToInt32(gv_pedidos.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Values["idPedido"].ToString());

    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Server=localhost\SQLEXPRESS;Database=Kirchesch;Trusted_Connection=True;");
    SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(@"DELETE FROM pedidosFeitos WHERE idPedido = @idPedido", con);

    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idPedido", idPedido);

    con.Open();

    com.ExecuteNonQuery();

    con.Close();

    preencheGrid();
}
```

This is the back-end of my code, the error I'm getting is on the variable `idPedido`, the third line.

Comment: Why are you taking a variable that is probably a number converting to a string and then back to a number?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

Just use Convert.ToInt32(e.RowIndex);

The datakey is selected for the operation from the selected row index

Comment: You solved my problem, but there is another thing, its getting the RowIndex, i want to get the RowIndex ID, cuz its trying to delete the element whit ID = 0 in my database. and this element does not even exist anymore

Answer (score 0):

You can get `idPedido` like this in `RowDeleting` event:

```
int idPedido = int.Parse(gv_pedidos.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("idPedido").toString());
```